# Allow connection selenium Standalone server with python scripts

Tags: python, selenium, connection

I've write a script in python for a bot that run using selenium, untill now I used the normal selenium webdriver, but now I want to move to Selenium Standalone server.
I have 2 servers on DigitalOcean, I want to use one server as the selenium standalone server and the other for send the requests.

In the Main server I run `java -jar ~/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar` for run the Selenium server, and it works.

In the second I have my scripts but I can't figure out how to allow the connection.

My options for run the webdriver are:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/var/www/users/'+ Setup.db +'/cookies')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('CHROME')
browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://MAIN_SERVER_IP:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

But I can't run the webriver, I see that the 2 servers are "talking" beacause when I try to run the script, in the main server I read `Only local connections are allowed.` so that mean that there are some problem with the firewall or the settings but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try to change firewall settings: open Windows Defender Firewall and check the if python is allowed to make outbound connections or alternatively try the following command: "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=<your_python_path> dir=out action=block program=python.exe enable=yes profile=any"

Comment: @FedericoRubbi thanks for your reply, but i don't think its a local problem, I see the `Only local connections are allowed.` on the server that has the selenium standalone on it. So the 2 servers can comunicate